# How can i fix from url image bind with retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm connecting data with json using retrofit. I failed to link the existing image url on json. how can I do it.

There is no problem with the textview binding, as you can see
How can i bind to image?

JSON

```
holder.mDriverName.setText(filteredUserList.get(position).getId());
           holder.mStationName.setText(filteredUserList.get(position).getName());
           holder.mDistance.setText(filteredUserList.get(position).getUsername());
           holder.mScorePoint.setText(filteredUserList.get(position).getEmail());

      [
           {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "İsmail Hakkı Aydın",
              "station": "Çiçek Taksi",
              "distance": "1250",
              "score": "3",
              "profile": "https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=3"
            }
      ]
```

Comment: Use glide to load your image from url https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Glide library to load url into your imageView

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Example:

```js
Glide.with(context).load("http://....").into(imageView);
```

In your case it's gonna look like below:

```
Glide.with(context).load(filteredUserList.get(position).getProfile()).into(holder.mScorePoint);
```

Comment: I tried like this but did not; Glide.with(context).load(tokens.get(0)).into(holder.mProfile);

now, i did the your sample, sample worked, thank you!

Comment: good. glad it worked. study https://github.com/bumptech/glide carefully, it helps you a lot.